# How can i create multiple radio group with different names at run time

Tags: android

I have tried it. it works fine but for a single radio group if i iterate throuh a loop then i can only gets the first one values
....

```
RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(this); 
group.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
RadioButton btn1 = new RadioButton(this);
btn1.setText("BTN1");
group.addView(btn1);
RadioButton btn2 = new RadioButton(this);
group.addView(btn2);
btn2.setText("BTN2");
.... 
RadioButton btnN = new RadioButton(this);
group.addView(btnN);
btnN.setText("BTNN");
yourLayout.addView(group);
....
```

Comment: `but for a single radio group if i iterate through a loop then i can only gets the first one values` please show code where iterating through a loop

Comment: Try SetID  
and check this out:  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10763686/3487232